# Android autocomplete matching options

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am using an AutoCompleteTextView in my app which gives countries names suggestions. My autocomplete is matching the entered text with every word in the suggestions list. For example, if I enter the two letters "ar", I get "Saudi Arabia" as one of the suggestions.

Is there any way to make the AutoCompleteTextView tries to match only starting from the first word? i.e. the suggestion must start with entered text, in case of my previous example, I get suggestions like "Armenia", "Argentina" & "Aruba" only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `Filter` implementation within `ArrayAdapter` first checks if the string starts with the search constraint, and then splits the string and checks each individual word.

From ArrayAdapter.java:

```
// First match against the whole, non-splitted value
if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
    newValues.add(value);
} else {
    final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
    final int wordCount = words.length;

    // Start at index 0, in case valueText starts with space(s)
    for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
        if (words[k].startsWith(prefixString)) {
            newValues.add(value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

As Daniel mentioned, you will need to implement your own adapter that implements `Filterable`. I've created an example that achieves the behavior you're looking for. [You can find it here.](https://gist.github.com/bamatson/0b54a1a25eb6e4add40f) It reuses most of the code within `ArrayAdapter`, but omits the part that splits the strings.

Comment: Thanks you so much man! That was a great help, and I really appreciate you taking the time to write the whole example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an adapter, which supplies the items, and implements the [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface.

For using the Filterable in the adapter, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fjfish/3024308).

Basically you need to do a check with `abc.startsWith(xyz)`, and filter the results based on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I wrote a custom adapter and it worked.

Comment: Both answers are perfect and basically the same, I just accepted bmat's answer because he points out to the reason which causes my issue and his example is specific to my question. Again thank you both very much, I appreciate your effort.